# How should my ceiling light be connected to my wiring?

Tags: electrical

Switch has 2 black, 1 red attached to switch. Light has 2 black 2 white one red. When I attach it it won’t turn off. Light stays on. What wire is allowing that.

Comment: Pictures will help.  The two blacks at the switch should power to the switch and power to something else.  The red should be switch hot.  The light we need pictures on how the blacks are connected, could be to power other lights on the same switch, or a boo-boo.

Comment: Is the a replacement light?  How was the original light hooked up?

Comment: "When I attach it" - Which wires are you attaching?

Comment: @crip659: Unless this is part of a three-way... which was my first thought for black/black/red in the US. If course color conventions may be different elsewhere in the world; please edit the question to specify that.

Comment: Pictures of the _original_ wiring would be extremely helpful. You did take those so you could figure out how to put it back together, didn't you? No? Well, you're not the first...